# How to make function appear in sentence?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

I have a function to show theme details and want to put it in a sentence.
Like: The "theme" developed by "author". And it will contain links.

I tried printf, did get the correct result.

```
    function logbook_info() {
    $theme_logbook = wp_get_theme();
    echo esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'TextDomain' ) );
    echo esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'ThemeURI' ) );
    echo esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'AuthorURI' ) );
}

add_action( 'logbookinfo', 'logbook_info' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to display theme detail sentence. I have use  `wp_footer` action,You can change hook as per your requirement.

```
function logbook_info() {
    $theme_logbook = wp_get_theme();
    $theme_name = esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'Name' ) );
    $theme_uri = esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'ThemeURI' ) );
    $theme_author = esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'Author' ) );
    $theme_author_uri = esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'AuthorURI' ) );

    $theme_html = '<a href="'.$theme_uri.'">'.$theme_name.'</a>';
    $author_html = '<a href="'.$theme_author_uri.'">'.$theme_author.'</a>';

    echo "The ".$theme_html." developed by ".$author_html;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'logbook_info' );
```

It will add theme detail in footer : https://prnt.sc/qhva3o

Answer (score 0):

```
function logbook_info() {
    $theme_logbook = wp_get_theme();
    echo 'The'.esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'TextDomain' ) ). 'Developed by '.
    esc_html( $theme_logbook->get( 'AuthorURI' ) );
}

add_action( 'logbookinfo', 'logbook_info' );
```

Try this.